# woocommerce add function when admin changes product's attributes

Tags: woocommerce

I am relatively new to woocommerce development so I am sorry if this question might be too trivial but I need help.

I need in my application a way to make some checks when an admin makes changes to a product in woocommerce.
For example, I want to create a log file of all the changes that occurred on products. Who made them, when and what was the change (price, inventory, description, etc.).

I understand that there are hooks in woocommerce that I can use. Which ones can help me do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `post_updated` hook for this purpose, place the following code in your `functions.php`

```
function product_update_handler( $id, $before_data, $after_data ) { 
    if( $before_data->post_type == "product" ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();      
        error_log( $before_data->post_title ." has been updated by ".$current_user->user_login );

    }   
}

add_action('post_updated', 'product_update_handler', 0, 3);
```

you have two product objects ( before update, after update ) with the above hook, you can compare both object and log the changes.